# How to modify data from an InfuxDB query?

Tags: time-series, influxdb, flux-influxdb, chronograf

I'm used flux to consult a database in Infuxdb. The sensors that collect data for some reason record too high or low data for the field they are measuring. An example could be temperature above 100 cº.
For cases like this I would like to change the data when query the database and not in the database itself.

For example, if for a specific date the temperature in the database is 150 cº, I want to make a flux query that change this data for another more likely (35 cº for example), but that in the database the 150 cº value is maintained.

Another element to consider is how to obtain the new value. I know that influexDB admits interpolation, but in versions greater than 2.0 and mine is 1.8.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use [map](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0/stdlib/universe/map) function, like

```js
data
    |> map(fn: (r) => ({ r with _value: if r["_value"] > 100.0 then r["_value"] - 100.0 else r["_value"] }))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I need an interpolation way to change the value and not an if condition.